# Insert/read a set into a map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, set, composition

I want to 'manage' flights, using `map<string, set<string>>`. The `string` keys represents the flight number while the `set<string>` values represent the people's name registered onto the flight. In my case, I read data from a simple text file such as:

```
123 jhonny
132 harry
123 bill
145 herry
132 jarry
```

in order to find the people in the same flight.

I know that a basic way to insert into a map is

```
map<string, string> m;
m["hi"] = test;
```

and using the iterator to read the container.

But how can I insert and read the composition of a set into a map?

I tried with a double iterator, or using the while and a iterator to take data from a file:

```
string pers, volo;
while (wf >> volo >> pers) {
    m[volo] = pers;
}
```

but it gives error.

I'm new in STL and I've read some files, guide, and others to learn sets and maps, but I haven't found anything about container composition (such as the one I've described). How can I do that? Perhaps with a double iterator on map and on set?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just treat your `m[volo]` like any kind of regular set. Your `set` will be default-constructed once you access its value using [`std::map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at). This allows you to directly use any of `set`'s member functions. To add a value to the set, use [`std::set::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert).

Here's what your code might look like using standard input/output:

```
string a, b;
while (cin >> a >> b) {
    m[a].insert(b);
    cout << m[a].size() << endl;
}
```

---

If you want to output your set, a convenient way to do this would be to define an overload over `operator<<`. The following defines a template any set.

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::set<T>& s)
{
    for (auto& el : s)
        os << el << ' ';
    return os;
}
```

This allows you to do the following without any errors.

```
for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
{
    cout << it->first;   // a string
    cout << ' ';
    cout << it->second;   // a set
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: ahh ok it seems to work thanks (though i have no understand good how methods works). And to read it? I tried with    '''map<string, set<string>>::iterator iter = m.begin();
            for (; iter != m.end(); ++iter) {
                cout << iter->first << " " << iter->second << endl;
            } ''' but it gives errors in operator << (i have iostream included and namespace std)

Comment: @Romans Your code and error description should be in [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54327128/edit) but okay. `iter->second` has a type of `set`, doesn't it? `cout` doesn't know how to handle that. You'll probably want a second loop working with `set::iterator`. (You can also define an `operator<<` that will accept `std::set`s, but this may be a bit challenging.)

Comment: @TrebuchetMS the default program at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ has a `<<` for `vector`, you can just swap in `set` to that